# Lookup data from 1 table to other table in R

Tags: r

I have a databse 1 in which I have columns

country      region   area     houseno
bangladesh   south    block1    C1
bangladesh   south    block1    C2
bangladesh   north    block12    C2

Another Database in which i have columns 
Area     Tax  muncipality
block1   50   F1
block2   30   F2
block3   40   F1

The key to do the lookup is block

I want to move column B2 from database 2 to matching cases in database 1
how can i do this in R

Comment: To match which column of data base 1? Could you provide a minimal reproducible example for your two data bases and further information regarding merging them?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want without a reproducible example, but you could do a left join by `block1` like this:

```
library(dplyr)
database1 %>% 
  left_join(other_database %>% select(block1, B2), by = c("block1"))
```

Comment: To do left join should the column name in both the file be same?

Comment: Yes the key should be the same with my solution (`block1`). If it is not the same use `by = c("name_of_key_column_database_1", "name_of_key_column_database_1"`.

Comment: Error: `by` can't contain join column `block1` which is missing from LHS

Comment: It should work because you wrote that database1 contains a variable called `block1`. Please add a reproducible example using `dput` so we can help you better.